# Why does the Google Datastore console behave differently to the GAE Java library for Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google App Engine + Java app which has been happily running for many years (using JDO + datastore for persistence) and I have had no problem (*occasionally, and reluctantly*) updating a property of an entity in the Google Datastore console manually.

Recently (maybe the last 2-3 months) I have noticed a change in behaviour which breaks our app. I do not understand exactly what's going wrong or how we could handle it.

So my question is:
Why is it behaving differently and what can I do about it?

Let me first try to explain the behaviour I am seeing and then show my smallest possible replicating test case.

Suppose you had a simple persistence class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Account implements Serializable {

@Persistent private ShortBlob testShortBlob;
@Persistent private String name;
// ...etc...

}
```

If I edited the name via the Datastore web console in the past, it would work as expected, the name field would change and everything else would work fine.

The behaviour I am seeing now is that after saving the entity via the console, I can no longer query and load the entity in JDO, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.ShortBlob
```

Which points to some underlying datastore change that means that ShortBlob field is having it's type change from ShortBlob to Blob (even though I make no edits to that field via the console).

This test case will replicate the issue:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
// this one really is a ShortBlob - will load fine in JDO
Entity account = new Entity("Account", "123");
account.setProperty("name", "Test Name");
account.setUnindexedProperty("testShortBlob", new ShortBlob("blah".getBytes()));

datastore.put(account);
// this one really is not a ShortBlob, its a blob - it will fail for the same reason I am seeing in production.
account = new Entity("Account", "124");
account.setProperty("name", "Test Name 2");
account.setUnindexedProperty("testShortBlob", new Blob("blah".getBytes()));
datastore.put(account);

// then load the entity via JDO

 try {
    accountFromJdo = pm.getObjectById(Account.class, key);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("We get here, the object won't load with the ClassCast Exception");
  }
```

So that's the issue, but why would saving via the cloud datastore console be changing the ShortBlob's to Blob?

My workaround currently is to set the ShortBlob fields to null in the Datastore console - that will then allow the entity to load. But that sucks if the data in the blob is important!

**Update:**

I have been doing more testing on this, using the low-level JSON API to see if I could se a difference in the raw JSON responses before and after saving the entity via console. The good news is, I can!

Before editing the entity via the console, a shortBlob field saved to the Datastore via the JDO App Engine interface will look like this:

```
        },
        "testShortBlob": {
          "blobValue": "tNp7MfsjhdfjkahsdvfkjhsdvfIItWyzy6glmIrow4WWhRPbhQ/U+MGX3opVvpxu"
        },
```

But if I go in to the Datastore console, and edit the entity (leave the blob field unchanged, edit an unrelated field, such as name. Now when I run the same query I get:

```
        },
        "testShortBlob": {
          "blobValue": "tNp7MfsjhdfjkahsdvfkjhsdvfIItWyzy6glmIrow4WWhRPbhQ/U+MGX3opVvpxu",
          "excludeFromIndexes": true
        },
```

Subtle difference, but I think it's important, according to [the Java docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) `ShortBlob` are indexed, and `Blob` are not.

[image]

So I think my question now is: why does editing an entity via the Cloud Datastore console change the indexed status of blob fields?

Comment: I believe this is a bug, the datastore console should not change index status of properties when saving, so I have raised an issue in the tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79547492

Comment: this bug has been fixed, in the meantime I found I was able to repair the broken entities using the Datastore API (not the JDO API) by settings the value back to ShortBlob using the bytes from the blob, something like: .setProperty(prop, new ShortBlob(((Blob) value).getBytes()));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed question and debugging. This seems fishy.  I will make sure https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79547492 gets assigned to the correct team.

As far as workarounds go:

The JSON API you noticed is [Cloud Datastore API v1](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/cloud%20datastore/datastore/v1/) there are a variety of [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to help make it easy to access.

It is possible to use that API to transactionally read/modify/write entities.  In your case it would allow you to perform the desired transforms.  Alternatively, making modifications through JDO would also work.